# Emacs & PHP indenting question

Tags: php, emacs

I'm a bit new to using emacs for webdevelopment.
I am using php-mode and i am happy with it.
There is only one issue i have which causes me a lot of problems because of our company's coding style.

When i have a function, e.g.:

```
$instance = new Model('foo', 'bar');
```

And I want to indent it like this:

```
$instance = new Model(
    'foo',
    'bar'
);
```

Emacs does the following when i insert a newline before the first argument and indents it like this:

```
$instance = new Model(
                      'foo',
                      'bar'
);
```

Can anyone point me in a direction on how i can configure/change this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

php-mode is actually build on top of cc-mode, so you can use cc-mode's indentation customization capabilities. Have a look [here](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/cc-mode_9.html).

Answer (score 1):

In you .emacs file of configuration add this line:

> (setq standard-indent X)

Being X the amount of spaces you want to indent while hitting TAB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The indenting is fine after braces but not when I try to put the parameters of a function call onto the next line, see my example.

Comment: Then check this answer, it may suit your needs about indenting with emacs:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475279/how-to-control-indentation-after-an-open-parenthesis-in-emacs