# Emacs modeline at the end of file in one line

Tags: emacs

I am working on a project where some people use vi, some use emacs and some others (including gedit). The most simple yet global way (although not perfect) to enforce (at least visual) style was to add the following lines to the end of each file:

```
  ...
  return 0;
}
// Editor modelines  -  generated by http://www.wireshark.org/tools/modelines.html
// Local variables:
// c-basic-offset: 4
// tab-width: 4
// indent-tabs-mode: t
// truncate-lines: 1
// End:
// vim:set ft=cpp ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 nowrap: cindent:
```

the question is: how can I convert the emacs portion in a "one-line" code (as vim can)? and yet keep it at the end of the source file (not at the top).

(Probably this can be recasted as Lisp question but I am not familiar with it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `eval:` declaration, but Emacs will ask you to confirm that it is safe to evaluate. If you tell Emacs to accept it permanently, it won't ask about that expression again (it stores it in `safe-local-variable-values` in the custom-set-variables section of your init file).

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; eval:(setq c-basic-offset 4 tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t truncate-lines 1)
;;; End:
```

You can wrap multiple expressions in `progn`:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; eval:(progn (setq c-basic-offset 4) (message "hello"))
;;; End:
```

Or use any other constructs (I don't think there are any restrictions).

Comment: thanks, I am using this one now. It seems that the modeline can't be shorted than three line if at the end of the file.

Comment: Having looked at Lindydancer's answer, it occurred to me that Directory Local Variables hadn't been mentioned. You might prefer to use those instead (see my newer answer).

Comment: I just wanted to add that, at least in my case, emacs never marks that these options are safe even after asking whether they should be marked as safe and answering with '!' (permanently add). The long syntax is accepted though.

Comment: alfC: That's curious. I've only ever encountered that behaviour when `user-init-file` is not set (e.g. due to running Emacs with the `-q` argument)

Comment: phils: I tried in a different system and worked as expected (Ubuntu/GNU Emacs 22.2.1). In the first system (Ubuntu/GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1) didn't worked even after deleting .emacs and .emacs.d. It will remain a mystery probably. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Directory Local Variables are probably a better approach.

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

The single `.dir-locals.el` file will be processed by everyone, and no need for file local variables at all.

vim may well have a similar mechanism?

Comment: good tip. it is a good option specially for a project that is already started with tons of files. (although being a hidden file can be confusing, ... or not)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `// Local Variables:` and `// End:`.  The rest can be made into one line as in `// eval: (setq c-basic-offset 4 tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t truncate-lines 1)`.

Comment: thanks for making clear that the code can't be shorter than three lines

Answer (score 0):

`(setq c-basic-offset 4 tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t truncate-lines 1)` add this to your .emacs. If you wish to do this for specific file types you can always use the add-hook call, such as `(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'your-func-here)` where your-func-here could be a function that simply sets those variables.

Refer to phils method of using Local Variables and eval to accomplish this with the first line of code given above. Sorry I didn't quite understand that this was only for a single file or very few files.

Comment: No. That will make it the standard for all files.

Comment: Still won't work. That will set it for all files of in that mode. The OP wants to set it only for a single file.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought since it was a project it might be all C files or c++ files etc....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be SOL:

Specifying File Variables: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

Variables in Emacs:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Variables.html#Variables

Unless you use Phils's eval style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to turn the question around? Do you really need any file-local variables? If you use the same style throughout all source files, it might be better to define a C indentation setup and distribute this among all developers.

```
(defconst my-c-style
  '((c-basic-offset . 2)
    (c-offsets-alist
     . ((substatement-open     . 0)
        (statement-case-open   . +)
        (inline-open           . 0)
        (arglist-cont-nonempty . (c-indent-operator-lineup-arglist-operators
                                  c-lineup-arglist)))))
  "My indentation style")

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (interactive)
  (c-add-style "my" my-c-style t))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: thanks for recommendation, I will consider it. also How would you set the options in your example in a LocalVariables/End block?

Comment: I don't. I simply place the code I posted in `~/.emacs`. Or rather, I would place it in a versioned-controlled file, distribute it to all users, and ask them to incude it from their init file. That way you could tweak the indentation style and easily push out the change to everyone.

Comment: I know the code if for `~/.emacs` I just wanted to test the options in single file. I never know how to translate one syntax into the other, your code look very different (for example the dots and the nested parenthesis) from what I would see in a LocalVariables/End block.